# How to parse Collection<PSObject> when it is in tabular format by using Format-Table command

Tags: c#, powershell-remoting

I am using PowerShell cmdlet viz. Get-SPUser through **C# program** as follows

*`*Get-SPUSer** -web <siteCollection> | **format-table** Name,LoginName....`

After I invoke this command it gives me ouptut in form of **Collection< PSObject >**

Now I want to traverse this collection of PSObject to get the actual records i.e. users with values of properties mentioned in command.

I want to use format-table instead of select-object. 
How to parse collection of PSObject to fetch property=value of user using C# ?

Comment: Why do you want to use format-table?  It's not a parsing cmdlet, AFAIK. Also, if it's a collection of objects, does it implement IEnumerable? Then you could just use a standard C# foreach loop. Sorry if this doesn't help, just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: @RonThompson : because Select-Object is taking 13 mins to fetch just 1000 users and format-table ( or for that matter format-list ) gives it in 5 seconds. Why is it not possible ? as it provides same output as that of select-object ?

Comment: Because it doesn't provide the same output. It's a completely different object that happens to look similar. It's purpose is presentation, only, and in Powershell, it can't be piped to anything but an Out-Cmdlet without tears resulting.   However, if you insist on trying it, here's a link you might find helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18287936-2d8c-4ba8-a3f5-46caf7b4c62c/c-with-powershell-and-pscustomobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** other way but to use **Out-String** cmdlet using pipe which provides output in flat string format. Command is as follows

**Get-SPUSer -web  *SiteCollection*  | format-list -property *prop1, prop2 ..* | Out-String**

After removing newline/carriage returns and splitting techniques with string, I am able to get expected output.
This is very crud way of achieving it but I have no choice.
If select-object command has provided good performance then I would have go for it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but I've personally not enjoyed trying to make Powershell play well with others. If I were in your shoes, I'd start with this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6e9b3606-4ee7-4253-bafc-0058d9fe2a71/how-to-get-spuser-from-display-name-with-c-code and work with C# entirely or Powershell entirely and see what I could get done there.